# Typescript - How Do I Get A Typed Array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

My Sample use case.

```
type someEnum = 'a' | 'b';

const someObj: { [K in someEnum]: string } = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
};

const a: Array<someEnum> = ['a', 'b'];

// In Future update someEnum

type someEnum = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

// Gives an error;

// Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: string; b: string; }' 
// but required in type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; }'.

const someObj: { [K in someEnum]: string } = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
};

// No error;
const a: Array<someEnum> = ['a', 'b'];

// Is There someThing like;

// const typedArray: [K in someEnum]
```

It would be really cool to have such a feature;
Is there some functionality to achieve the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `type typedArray = Array<someEnum>;` - or what feature are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's tempting to use some workaround to get [tuple to union, please don't use it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-514082646).

You can work around this issue in several ways, the simplest way is if the enum is under your control, start from the array instead of the enum:

```
const allPosibilitieForSomeEnum = ['a',  'b' , 'c'] as const
type someEnum = typeof allPosibilitieForSomeEnum[number];
```

You could use an object instead and use `keys` to get the keys.

Or you could use a function that validates that all memebers are present:

```
type someEnum = 'a' | 'b' | "c";

function checkEnum<TEnum>() {
    return function <TActual extends TEnum[]>(...p: TActual & ([TEnum] extends [TActual[number]] ? {} : {
        error: ["Array does not contain all members, expected: ", TEnum, "found:", TActual[number]]
    })) {
        return p
    }
}

const someObj =  checkEnum<someEnum>()("a", "b", "c") 
const someObj2 =  checkEnum<someEnum>()("a", "b") ///  Property 'error' is missing in type '["a", "b"]' but required in type '{ error: ["Array does not contain all members, expected: ", someEnum, "found:", "a" | "b"]; }'.
```

Comment: This seems to be the most viable approach, but i guess we cannot index the enum as in we cannot do `allPosibilitieForSomeEnum.a`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a tuple out of a union type. That is indeed possible but a little bit more complex. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298) in the TypeScript Github repository that adresses this.

One of the [answers](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-482330241) there seems to work pretty well. Here the example in [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgd0QS2BAPAFQDRQDKUEAHpgHYAmAzlAIYUgB8UAvFAN5QDaAClDQUoAawggA9gDMoOALoAuIvzlQAvgG4AUKEiyArmAA2EAKoUaACzRTguEuQjU6jEDzkEAGqw44HlWgYmKAB+KAAKcNIlTwIAOgTgJRwASnZWOAk0KjSyALpwhLikwQopJCgAJTS2DKyqUKqoJQoIBERmqFb27V1oHEMTPn0rezynQNd3Lx9ZfwmXYLD4JFQMbAHjMwtrW1wCV2YCPwAyLl5oqBpgdAoAc0UoT3VWFrakbR1waHM0CQocBJNiYsKZZr9-oDgRBKhAAMb6RA0NAIIwgLDTKBgz59LEUP4AoGDGHwxHI1HovzjZxBNweLGzThaKAsqAARmS2lZUAADEoIYTobCEUiURA0QB9fZYgjYrRqHg8UyqamBHjdJCqMJszo8uRaL56AVQ4nCsliyVjRw0qb00wEQg+Zms4iqxYgRrGolbM2iim4YnmKw2Oz4IisAA+Bi2w1GYcdBAAoqQ4UZ9FRsPbw68uu9EJ8TMAoJcvdCsDqowAmKBRgDMNagABZZjw2QRKwRawRG3JtIWoCB+fjId6QRWoNW6w3m+xeI3O+2CGze0A).

Comment: Please, please make sure you udenrstand what you are getting into before using this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-514082646

Comment: Is'nt there a 'cleaner' way of doing this ?

Comment: No, currently there is no cleaner way - except for doing this the other way around. Creating the tuple type yourself and infer the union type.